# Why does running build_frameworks.sh fail?

Tags: audiokit

Running the `build_frameworks.sh` script sometimes results in this cryptic error. Why does it do it and how can I fix it

```
~/Code/AudioKit/AudioKit () ./Frameworks/build_frameworks.sh 
cat: ../VERSION: No such file or directory
Building frameworks for platforms: iOS macOS tvOS
Ignoring configuration file 'simulator.xcconfig' because it could not be loaded.
        Reason: File could not be parsed due to preprocessing errors:
    The file “simulator.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. (/Users/username/Code/AudioKit/AudioKit/simulator.xcconfig)Build settings from command line:
    BUILD_DIR = /Users/username/Code/AudioKit/AudioKit/build
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator11.0

xcodebuild: error: '../AudioKit/iOS/AudioKit For iOS.xcodeproj' does not exist.
~/Code/AudioKit/AudioKit () cd Frameworks/
```

Answer (score 4):

The `build_frameworks.sh` script must be run from the `Frameworks/` directory! `cd` into that directory to run the script and you should have better success. :)

Comment: Indeed, most of the scripts in the `Frameworks` directory are meant to be run straight from there, not anywhere else.

Comment: And if you want to be extra cool, modify the shell script to query if the current directory includes "build_frameworks.sh" and report an error if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

As of AudioKit 4.0.3, this problem is gone:

```
⋊> ~/D/AudioKit on develop ⨯ ./Frameworks/build_frameworks.sh           23:46:08
This script needs to be run from the Frameworks folder
```

Via https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/commit/c85fbc714c172338f9586074315602dda8051d71