# './build_frameworks.sh' fails with `xcodebuild: error: '../AudioKit.xcodeproj' does not exist.`

Tags: audiokit

First time installation of AudioKit with:

-OS X 10.15.5 (19F101)
-XCode Version 12.0.1 (12A7300)

For other people's benefit: running ./build_frameworks.sh initially complained with:

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

This seemed to be resolved after running:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Running it again gave a slew of complains like this:

```
/Users/ali/Documents/Development/AudioKit: error: manifest parse error(s):
<module-includes>:5:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:5:
#import "copyfile.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/copyfile.h:41:9: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'
typedef uint32_t copyfile_flags_t;
        ^
<module-includes>:5:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:5:
#import "copyfile.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/copyfile.h:62:44: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'
int copyfile_state_get(copyfile_state_t s, uint32_t flag, void * dst);
                                           ^
<module-includes>:5:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:5:
#import "copyfile.h"
        ^
...
```

Ending with this:

```
...
/Users/ali/Documents/Development/AudioKit/Package.swift:4:8: error: failed to build module 'PackageDescription' from its module interface; it may have been damaged or it may have triggered a bug in the Swift compiler when it was produced
import PackageDescription
       ^
Building frameworks for version 5.0 on platforms: iOS macOS tvOS
Building static frameworks for iOS / iphoneos
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project ../AudioKit.xcodeproj -target AudioKit -xcconfig device.xcconfig -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos BUILD_DIR=/Users/ali/Documents/Development/AudioKit/Frameworks/build CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION=5.0 clean build

Build settings from command line:
    BUILD_DIR = /Users/ali/Documents/Development/AudioKit/Frameworks/build
    CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 5.0
    SDKROOT = iphoneos14.0

Build settings from configuration file 'device.xcconfig':
    APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_HEADERS = YES
    BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE = bitcode
    CLANG_ENABLE_MODULE_DEBUGGING = NO
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = 
    CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED = NO
    DEFINES_MODULE = YES
    ENABLE_BITCODE = YES
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO

xcodebuild: error: '../AudioKit.xcodeproj' does not exist.
```

I see that the author addressed a similar question in [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921133/why-does-running-build-frameworks-sh-fail) but I am running the script from within the Frameworks folder so I don't think this is my issue....

Comment: Using AudioKit5 (v5beta) this from the README works fine for adding AudioKit to an iOS app:




"To add AudioKit to your Xcode project, select File -> Swift Packages -> Add Package Depedancy. Enter `https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit` for the URL."